# How to compare jar files using Ant?

Tags: ant, jar

Using Ant, is it possible to compare two JAR files to determine if they are equivalent?

- Class files will have different create timestamps. This should not count as a difference.
- Ideally, the compare should ignore manifest file

Answer (score 0):

I did find some articles where you may fully or partially achieve what you want. You may check for possibilities to create a batchscript and call it in the ant script.

http://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?command_line_reference.html